# How do I add custom content at the bottom of the product category page?

Tags: category

My B2C has different product categories. I want to add some custom content at the bottom of each product category page, such as: text, banner image. I know that the product category is the same module that is called uniformly, so it is not clear how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with creating a static block and set it to widgets. please find below screen-shot.

hope it may help to solve your issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. How to control this widget at the bottom of the product category?

Comment: Please check with containers options.